# Errors initializing 2d char array to test printing

Tags: java, arrays, printing, char, multidimensional-array

My air-plane seating chart is not printing correctly. I get a long list of errors only when entering a pre-initialized array. I am unsure what I am currently doing wrong, but it does not function.

```
import java.util.*;
public class AirplaneSeating
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
        int rows = 2;
        int c, c2;
        char[][] seatsLeft = new char[rows][3];
        char[][] seatsRight = new char[rows][3];
        seatsLeft = {{'-','-','-'},{'-','-','-'},{'-','-','-'}};
        seatsRight = {{'-','-','-'},{'-','-','-'},{'-','-','-'}};
        System.out.println("        A B C  D E F");
        for (c = 0; c < 6; c++)
        {
            System.out.print("Row  " + (c + 1) + " ");
            for (c2 = 0; c2 < 3; c2++)
            {
                System.out.print(seatsLeft[c2] + " ");
            }
            System.out.print("  ");
            for (c2 = 0; c2 < 3; c2++)
            {
                System.out.print(seatsRight[c2] + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Here are the errors I'm getting:

```
AirplaneSeating.java:11: error: illegal start of expression
    seatsLeft = {{'-','-','-'},{'-','-','-'},{'-','-','-'}};
                ^
                                   ^
AirplaneSeating.java:12: error: <identifier> expected
    seatsRight = {{'-','-','-'},{'-','-','-'},{'-','-','-'}};
              ^
```

EDIT: Here is the code that I have fixed so far and I get no more errors.

```html
import java.util.*;
public class AirplaneSeating
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
        int rows = 3;
        int c, c2;
        char[][] seatsLeft = {{ '-', '-', '-' },{ '-', '-', '-' },
        { '-', '-', '-' }};
        char[][] seatsRight = {{ '-', '-', '-' },{ '-', '-', '-' },
        { '-', '-', '-' }};
        System.out.println("        A B C  D E F");
        for (c = 0; c < rows; c++)
        {
            System.out.print("Row  " + (c + 1) + " ");
            for (c2 = 0; c2 < 3; c2++)
            {
                System.out.print(seatsLeft[c2] + " ");
            }
            System.out.print("  ");
            for (c2 = 0; c2 < 3; c2++)
            {
                System.out.print(seatsRight[c2] + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

But it prints out like this: 
       A B C  D E F
Row  1 [C@55f96302 [C@55f96302 [C@55f96302   [C@3d4eac69 [C@3d4eac69 [C@3d4eac69 
Row  2 [C@55f96302 [C@55f96302 [C@55f96302   [C@3d4eac69 [C@3d4eac69 [C@3d4eac69 
Row  3 [C@55f96302 [C@55f96302 [C@55f96302   [C@3d4eac69 [C@3d4eac69 [C@3d4eac69

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do this

```
char[][] seatsLeft = {{'-','-','-'},{'-','-','-'},{'-','-','-'}};
char[][] seatsRight = {{'-','-','-'},{'-','-','-'},{'-','-','-'}};
```

Or do it in a loop like

```
char[][] seatsLeft = new char[rows][3];
char[][] seatsRight = new char[rows][3];
for(int i=0i<rows;i++){
    for(int j=0;j<3;j++){
        seatsLeft[i][j]='-';
        seatsRight[i][j]='-';
    }
}
```

You cannot do it like this

```
char[][] seatsLeft = new char[rows][3];
char[][] seatsRight = new char[rows][3];
seatsLeft = {{'-','-','-'},{'-','-','-'},{'-','-','-'}};
seatsRight = {{'-','-','-'},{'-','-','-'},{'-','-','-'}};
```

because you have already initialized your array when you do `char[][] seatsLeft = new char[rows][3];` !

As you see how we have used 2 loop to initialize you have to use 2 loops to print as well.

```
for(int i=0;i<rows;i++){
    System.out.println("Row " + (i + 1));
    for(int j=0;j<3;j++){
        System.out.print(" "+seatsLeft[i][j]);
    }
    System.out.print(" ");
    for(int j=0;j<3;j++){
        System.out.print(" "+seatsRight[i][j]);
    }
    System.out.println("");
}
```

---

## **EDIT:**

it prints out like this: A B C D E F Row 1 [C@55f96302 [C@55f96302 [C@55f96302 [C@3d4eac69 [C@3d4eac69 [C@3d4eac69 Row 2 [C@55f96302 [C@55f96302 [C@55f96302 [C@3d4eac69 [C@3d4eac69 [C@3d4eac69 Row 3 [C@55f96302 [C@55f96302 [C@55f96302 [C@3d4eac69 [C@3d4eac69 [C@3d4eac69

for you because you have to understand that you are doing

```
 System.out.print(seatsLeft[c2] + " ");
 System.out.print(seatsRight[c2] + " ");
```

You need to understand that what you are doing is on an 2d array. seatsLeft[c2] & seatsRight[c2] returns the address of that row that is what you are seeing.

Comment: Won't display correctly because of `System.out.print(seatsLeft[c2] + " ");` and `System.out.print(seatsRight[c2] + " ");`.

Comment: Thank you! IS the wrong displa you are getting similar to this?       A B C  D E F
Row  1 [C@55f96302 [C@3d4eac69 [C@42a57993   [C@75b84c92 [C@6bc7c054 [C@232204a1 
Row  2 [C@55f96302 [C@3d4eac69 [C@42a57993   [C@75b84c92 [C@6bc7c054 [C@232204a1 
Row  3 [C@55f96302 [C@3d4eac69 [C@42a57993   [C@75b84c92 [C@6bc7c054 [C@232204a1

Comment: I'm getting it as  A B C  D E F
Row 1
 - - -  - - -
Row 2
 - - -  - - - Can you check if you have copied the code correctly ?

Comment: I attached the code at the bottom of my post that I modified to get it to run off what people suggested. The original was correct code I copied except for the IOException that I removed just before posting but accidentally left in the post.

Comment: Thanks a lot for helping me. I added a second bracket with [c] in it and it works perfect. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You have two main problems in this program-
1. You need not to have throw IOException,or if you need that for any further purpose than import java.io.IOException;

2. initialize your char[][] at point of defination i.e.

```html
char[][] seatsLeft = {{'-','-','-'},{'-','-','-'},{'-','-','-'}};
char[][] seatsRight = {{'-','-','-'},{'-','-','-'},{'-','-','-'}};
```

if you want to do it later do it element by element i.e. char[0][0]='-';

If you make this modifications your program will run.

Answer (score 0):

I see a few errors in your code, first your array assignments (using brackets) is only allowed on initial declaration of an array. Use the array `.length` property instead of hard coding the lengths. Then, to access and print the characters in a 2-d array you use both array indexes. Something like,

```
char[][] seatsLeft = { { '-', '-', '-' }, { '-', '-', '-' },
        { '-', '-', '-' } };
char[][] seatsRight = { { '-', '-', '-' }, { '-', '-', '-' },
        { '-', '-', '-' } };
System.out.println("        A B C  D E F");
for (c = 0; c < seatsLeft.length; c++) {
    System.out.print("Row  " + (c + 1) + " ");
    for (c2 = 0; c2 < seatsLeft[c].length; c2++) {
        System.out.print(seatsLeft[c][c2] + " "); // <-- [c][c2]
    }
    System.out.print("  ");
    for (c2 = 0; c2 < seatsRight.length; c2++) {
        System.out.print(seatsRight[c][c2] + " "); // <-- [c][c2]
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Or, using a [`for-each`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html) and formatted output,

```
for (c = 0; c < seatsLeft.length; c++) {
    System.out.printf("Row  %d ", c + 1);
    for (char ch : seatsLeft[c]) {
        System.out.printf("%c ", ch);
    }
    System.out.print("  ");
    for (char ch : seatsRight[c]) {
        System.out.printf("%c ", ch);
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```